# How to close socket

Tags: c++, sockets

Run c++ on Ubuntu.
I open socket in this way:

```
socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW))
```

What do i need to do in the end of the use?
Some socket will be used as long as the program run , do i need to check them from a while? to see if socket still exist?

Comment: @Ulterior how did you get to 501 reputation not knowing its proper name?

Comment: I am new to this kind of low programing. forgive me on this. i am java guy , no need to deal with network programming.

Comment: It also seems that this question is going to be treated as a file descriptor and be `close()`ed.

Comment: @H2CO3: Is it because its reputation returned `-1`?

Comment: @KerrekSB :D no, if it returns -1, creation had failed, so there's nothing to close.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The socket exists until you call `close` on its file descriptor. Since you have a raw IP socket, there's no notion of "being alive". Just close it when you're done using it.

Comment: Can you please explain or give reference why in raw socket there is no notion on being alive

Comment: @user1495181: No - *you* explain to my why there *should* be a notion of being alive. The socket just lets you send and receive data from the network. (Only a specialized socket like a TCP stream socket has a concept of liveness because it implements connection semantics. But that's *on top of* IP.)

Comment: better call shutdown before calling close.

Comment: It's worth to add that you need `#include <unistd.h>`

Answer (score 11):

As its docs/man page say, socket() returns an open file descriptor or -1 if it fails. That means you have to close it as you would close any other file descriptor:

```
close(sockfd);
```

Comment: closesocket(sockfd);